# I can't find my .minecraft folder on windows 10!

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I had just created an awesome world with lots of valuable loot. I had made a copy and deleted original and wanted to get it back, however I don't have a .Minecraft folder.

I have tried everything including download and the forums rules. I was told to reset Minecraft but just reset everything including my skins and worlds all together.

Comment: Are you playing the Java version or the windows 10 version?

Comment: Windows 10, sorry

Comment: So if you couldn't find the folder, how exactly did you make a copy to begin with?

Comment: @Nelson. He probably made a copy in-game.

Answer (score 5):

On Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition (if you installed it from the Windows Store) the files are saved here:

```
C:\Users\Name of User\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds
```

(Change "Name of User" to your User folder is called)

On Minecraft: Java Edition (if you downloaded it from Minecraft.net), it is found here:

```
C:\Users\Name of User\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
```